# How to get values of checkbox jquery in two separate arrays one contaings checked values and other unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Below is the code through which I get the values of checked input boxes:

```
$('#agent_region').click(function()
         {
           var ids = $('#agent_favourites_form  input:checked').map(function(){
             return this.value;
           }).get();
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "set_agent_favourites.php",
             data:  {map: ids},
             success: function(msg){
               $.jnotify(msg, 3000);
             }
           });
           return false;
         });
```

I want to get the values of unchecked checkboxes as well and pass it, I don't know how to pass two data: `{map : ids}, {map1 : ids1}` or something else. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `input:not(:checked)` and just add it into your data object:

```
$('#agent_region').click(function()
         {
           var ids = $('#agent_favourites_form  input:checked')
                       .map(function(){
                         return this.value;
                       }).get();
           var nonids = $('#agent_favourites_form  input:not(:checked)')
                          .map(function(){
                            return this.value;
                          }).get();
           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "set_agent_favourites.php",
             data:  {map: ids, unmap: nonids},
             success: function(msg){
               $.jnotify(msg, 3000);
             }
           });
           return false;
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery checked selector

See: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
$(function() {
    var checked = {};
    var unchecked = {};
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checked[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        } else {
            unchecked[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    // Only works with FireBug enabled
    console.debug(checked);
    console.debug(unchecked);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x3TcD/